# How do I resize a p5.Graphic object?

Tags: p5.js

In p5.js `resizeCanvas(x, y)` is a function for p5 objects but if I made a `p5.Graphics` object, can I resize it with a similar function?

Interestingly, `p5.Graphics` objects can run `resizeGraphics()` but nothing happens (including no error) and the height and width remain the same in the console.

```javascript
g = createGraphics(50, 50);   //creates p5.Graphics
g.resizeCanvas(100, 100);     //fails: silently without error
g.resize(100, 100);           //fails: resize has not been defined
```

Is there another function or would I need to actually extract the cooresponding graphics canvas and call a native javascript function instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resize a `P5.Graphics`, you can just create a new one, then draw the old one to the new one.

[Here](https://alpha.editor.p5js.org/KevinWorkman/sketches/Hyr9iM-xz) is an example:

```javascript
var pg;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 1000);
  pg = createGraphics(100, 100);
  pg.background(100);
  pg.noStroke();
  pg.ellipse(pg.width/2, pg.height/2, pg.width, pg.height);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);  
  image(pg, 0, 0);
}

function mouseClicked(){
    var newPG = createGraphics(mouseX, mouseY);
    newPG.image(pg, 0, 0, newPG.width, newPG.height);
    pg = newPG;
}
```

Comment: after inspecting elements, `createGraphics()` does actually create a canvas. It is just set to be invisible. I can remove it by calling `pg.canvas.remove()`. It's simple to do but I wasn't sure if there was a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score -2):

Using resizeCanvas on a graphics object created with "createGraphics" seems to stretch the graphics rather than resize the buffer.
Right now the best way to resize a graphics object is to simply set the width and height properties directly.

```
// Some graphics object
let graphics = createGraphics(w,h);

// Now simply resize like this
graphics.width = gWidth;
graphics.height = gHeight;
```

As suggested here:
https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/2064#issuecomment-315503533